# What happens if I skip the boot loader installation?

Tags: kali-linux, grub2

During my Kali Linux installation, I have the option to skip the boot loader installation.  If I don't install GRUB boot loader during
installation what state will my computer be in, and what can I do to move forward?

Comment: grub won't be installed on your hdd

Comment: Please only use formatting that makes sense.

Comment: And to your question: You might not be able to boot into Kali Linux but instead just the boot manager of your existing OS.

Comment: Give some context: What made you ask the question? Was it an instillation option? If so then state this in the question.

Comment: @richard  I edited the OP's question with what (I think) they were trying to ask...

Answer (score 4):

Then unless you've made other arrangements, it won't boot. If you have some other OS installed, its boot loader will probably continue to work, booting that other OS.

For example, if you already have a different Linux distro installed, you might decide to use its GRUB to boot the system, and add Kali to that grub. Or maybe you're going to use direct EFI booting, etc.

If you accidentally said no, you can boot the system with a rescue disc and then install GRUB (though since it's a fresh never-used install, just reinstalling may be easier).

Comment: I added to the question to try and make it actually answerable...

Comment: @Questionmark I'm unclear—are you the same person as Prakash Lakhara (just with two accounts)? If you're not, please ask your own question. If you are, you can ask the Stack Exchange team for an account merge (http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact)

Comment: I am defiantly not the same user!  I was just trying to make a better question out of it...  Did I make it worse?  I think that my edit was what the OP is really wondering...

Comment: @Questionmark Ah, OK... I was just confused by your comment. Anyway, I added some more to the answer to help if your edit is approved.

Answer (score 0):

The system works perfectly with pre installed OS,

If you already installed a Linux distro,for example Ubuntu;you will get default grub of 'ubuntu'

You can add Kali Linux to ubuntu's grub list by using 'grub customizer'.